# Mamp is not seeing localhost

Tags: php, localhost, mamp

In the MAMP menu bar>> Tools - I am seeing this:
phpMyAdmin(needs PHP5.5x to 7.0x)
SQLite Manager (needs PHP5.2.x or 5.3.x)

I have 8 sites on one shared database developed locally using MAMP. Never had a problem in the past. I cannot access any of the sites via localhost. - the last site I worked on required a newer version of PHP and I added V7.1.1 - the prior sites are run on earlier PHP versions, built full site using php 7.1.1 locally no problem. - That said, currently
 none of the sites will open via localhost.
The only thing I can think of is that I may have upgraded to OS Sierra and maybe that threw off a file?  I called Apple they recommend not touching the Apache settings.  I reinstalled Mamp, no change.

OS Sierra 10.12.3

MAMP V.4.1.1

PHP V. 7.1.1

I can connect to the internet, and my firewall is off.

I checked my host file - everything is there that should be with the exception of : "sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder"  which I read in an earlier thread -  do I need this?

localhost connection message:
"Unable to connect
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at localhost:8888."

I thought that by downloading the lastest version of MAMP I would be recieving the latest package of software such as apache,mysqyl and phpMyAdmin?

I humbly ask for any insight and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm having this same issue and just found this on google:

After you run the servers on MAMP/MAMP PRO

TRY THIS:
localhost:8888/phpmyadmin